Can I say: "I bought it for only half the price and I thought I got a steal"? Emphasis on "got"
be a steal: to be for sale at an unexpected low price
Does it always follow "be"? What about: I've just got a steal?

"I thought it was a steal" sounds more natural to me.

Certainly not with the present perfect.  "I just got a steal". It's street-talk in AmE.

I just got a steal on a lawn mower down at the hardware store. They're going out of business.

Speculation: the usage @TimR points out may have been influenced by the semantically close (and rhyming!) got a deal.

And there's the phrase "a steal of a deal".  We've got a steal of a deal for you at the Store of the Stars. So come on down!
Caption on FB page: "A steal of a deal!" : https://www.youtube.com/shorts/VC0dVL3_Kd0?feature=share

Sense 4 definition for a steal says


SINGULAR NOUN [a NOUN]
If you describe something as a steal, you mean that it is very good value.
[informal]
At only £13.50, this champagne is a steal.


The required form is just a steal.  We don’t need to precede this phrase with another BE.  This is fine:

I've just got a steal.

The use of the phrase with GET can be found here.

This is a "kinda sorta." If you were to say "got a steal," everyone would understand, and I doubt anyone would even consciously feel that it was "wrong." After all, we say that you "got" the item, and that the item is "a steal." But idiomatic usages mean that we just sometimes follow certain patterns and not others. This "ngram" chart shows that, while "got a steal" (or other tenses of "get") is not unheard of, and has risen in usage, it's nowhere near as common as most inflections of "be a steal." Furthermore, if you actually search Google Books (which powers the ngrams) for the phrase "got a steal," most of what you find is about baseball, in which "a steal" is the act of stealing a base.
So short version? You could say "got a steal." But it would be more idiomatic to use "is."

Can I say: "I bought it for only half the price and I thought I got a steal"? Emphasis on "got"
Yes.
“Got” is the past tense of “get” which is the verb for acquiring or coming into possession of something. It can be a tangible thing “I got the cake”, or not so tangible “I got the flu”, or even very intangible “I got the idea”.
“Be a steal” doesn’t work, you need the present tense of “be”: “Is a steal”.
Got is not inherently related to the verbs “be” or “have”, but both of those are involved in changing the tense of other verbs.
“I’ve just got a steal” or “I have just got a steal” is ok, you’re using have to create the perfect tense of “got” meaning that the “getting” is completed and in the past. North American English would tend to use “gotten” (which would also be my impulse as an Australian English speaker with the expanded form but not the contracted form) while British English would use “got”. Either is correct, “gotten” is the original form.
But “got” is unnecessary and a little clunky because “just” does the same work only better:

I have got a steal (At some unspecified time in the past, I got a steal, and that’s all over now)
I just got a steal (In the immediate past, I got a steal, and that’s all over now)
I’ve just got a steal (Why are you giving me redundant information?)


Might there be a transatlantic difference here? I think the Brits use "have just + past participle".

Can I say: "I bought it for only half the price and I thought I got a steal"? Emphasis on "got".
Sure, that's perfectly fine, but:

I'm not sure why you used the past tense with thought. Do you no longer think you got a steal?
I would say I bought it for half price instead of half the price.

Slightly modified version:

I bought it for half price and I think I got a steal.

Other expressions similar to "got a steal":

got a bargain
scored a deal (very informal)
made out like a bandit (idiom / very, very informal)


Oh, "thought" instead of "think" because it broke the very next month... And at first I used "the original price" but when I wrote it here I kind of forgot "original".

(1) That makes sense. You no longer think you got a steal because it broke, so you used the past tense. I just lacked the context to know that. (2) The most commonly used term is "half price.'
